# Why is there an orange cross going through my clips in premiere pro

Tags: video

Whenever I put an effect on one of my clips an orange 'X' goes through the display and the render. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this does not happen with every effect, just with those from Boris FX (Sapphire).

It's very likely you use a trial version and need to buy a license. Check here: https://borisfx.com/faq/sapphire-trial-watermark/

If you already have bought a license then something might went wrong during activation and you should contact them for further support.

Comment: Thanks Matt. But do you think I could get them for free?

Comment: They have a student license, I suppose it's free, here's the form: https://borisfx.com/support/student-license-request/ If you're not a student, you'll have to pay for it.